# CountDownTimer executes when it should not

Tags: java, android

I have a CountDownTimer inside a function. And this function is never called.
But onTick callback triggers. Why is that happens? What am I doing wrong?

```
public class tasksListActivity extends ListActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // code
    }

    private void find_locations_func(final Context mCon, final String direction) {
        Toast.makeText(mCon, "direction = " + direction, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new CountDownTimer(300000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        // some code
                        this.onFinish(); // this calls
                }

            public void onFinish() {
                goToLevel(mCon, dataAdapter, syncLayout);
            }
        }.start();
    }

}
```

So Toast doesn't appears but onFinish is called

Comment: post full code or check your code again.

Comment: how you are calling find_locations_func ?

Comment: find_locations_func(mCon, direction);

Comment: show the code part where you call `find_locations_func`. I think that you call it from background thread, and toast can't show from BG thread.